# parse.com cloudcode query, how to tell parse to return only certain columns of a PFObject found in a table?

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

I have this function on parse cloudcode:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testfunction", function(request, response) {

    var username = request.params.username
    var testObject = Parse.Object.extend('Test');
    var query = new Parse.Query(testObject);
    query.equalTo('username', username);
    // PFObject "Test" in the table has columns A,B and C
    // how do I tell the query that in the final result I send back 
    // in the response I only want filed A?

    query.find({
        success:function(results) {
            response.success(results)
        },
        error:function() {
            response.error('Could not find channels')
        }
    })
});
```

I am not sure how to tell the query to only return filed A and not field B and C as part of any of the PFObjects that come back from the query?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `select` method of the query to limit the fields that will be returned.

```
var username = request.params.username
var testObject = Parse.Object.extend('Test');
var query = new Parse.Query(testObject);
query.select('A');
query.equalTo('username', username);
```

It is a bit hidden in the documentation but you will find it in the *Query Constraints* section of the JavaScript Guide [1] (you will have to scroll down a bit there to find it).

[1] https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-constraints

Comment: ok, so, that almost works. Meaning, I went in and entered the three fields of the PFObject stored in the table I wanted to get. They come back fine. No matter what I do though it seems like "objectId", "createdAt", "updatedAt" and "__type" always get returned. Does that mean I cannot filter those out from the response?

Comment: I can't prove this now, but I would assume that, as these fields are 'core fields' on Parse, they will always be returned when you query information. What you could do is just returning a new object that just has the property of field A. So you wouldn't actually return the queried object 1:1 but only take out the information you need.

Comment: is there a way to exclude a field?